# oracle multiple partitions and sub-partitions for a huge number of entry

Tags: oracle, database-performance, database-partitioning

We have a table (Oracle) with a huge number of data (~400GB, about 360 millions of entry). On our frequent operations, we are selecting by two fields: one is a string (KEY), the second is a date (ENTRYTIME).

This is our table strucutre:

CREATE TABLE Table1
(
    "NAME" VARCHAR2(40 BYTE) not null,
    "KEY" VARCHAR2(90) not null,
    "ENTRYTIME" TIMESTAMP (6) not null,
    "REF" VARCHAR2(60 BYTE) not null,
)

My suggestion is to use partitions by the string, sub-partitions by the date, indexation for both and NOLOGGING for the table.

In details, I imagine that we can make 4 partitions based on the ASCII code range for the string's first char (the field KEY). E.g:

```
PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (32)
PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (64)
PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (96)
PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN (maxvalue)
```

And then, for each partition, we want create a 2 weeks sub-partitions, that means that we will have 26 sub-partitions/partition/year, so in total: 26*4=104 sub-partitions/year.

The goal is to run a purge job that drop a partition (the oldest) each 2 weeks.

In theory, and in my opinion, when we will INSERT a new record, Oracle will know directly where it is stored based on the string and the date. When we will SELECT, Oracle will know exactly from where to get it, because all our SELECT operations are based on the KEY, or on the ENTRYTIME, or both (faster).

What do you think about this partitioning? Do you think that this is better in term of perfs to have 104 sub-partitions than only one?

If Oracle can handle these 104 sub-partitions without problem, do you think that it can handle more, 208 (a sub-partition per week)?

Regards